# Crash on one activity in tablets

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have the following crash in my app:

```
11-12 14:27:10.180: E/AndroidRuntime(30384): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-12 14:27:10.180: E/AndroidRuntime(30384): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cookie.jar/com.cookie.jar.activities.SupportInformationActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-12 14:27:10.180: E/AndroidRuntime(30384):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
11-12 14:27:10.180: E/AndroidRuntime(30384):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
11-12 14:27:10.180: E/AndroidRuntime(30384):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
11-12 14:27:10.180: E/AndroidRuntime(30384):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
11-12 14:27:10.180: E/AndroidRuntime(30384):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-12 14:27:10.180: E/AndroidRuntime(30384):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-12 14:27:10.180: E/AndroidRuntime(30384):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
11-12 14:27:10.180: E/AndroidRuntime(30384):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-12 14:27:10.180: E/AndroidRuntime(30384):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-12 14:27:10.180: E/AndroidRuntime(30384):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
11-12 14:27:10.180: E/AndroidRuntime(30384):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
11-12 14:27:10.180: E/AndroidRuntime(30384):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-12 14:27:10.180: E/AndroidRuntime(30384): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-12 14:27:10.180: E/AndroidRuntime(30384):    at com.cookie.jar.utils.aUtils.getConnectionType(aUtils.java:160)
11-12 14:27:10.180: E/AndroidRuntime(30384):    at com.cookie.jar.fragments.SupportInfoFragment.populateValues(SupportInfoFragment.java:95)
11-12 14:27:10.180: E/AndroidRuntime(30384):    at com.cookie.jar.fragments.SupportInfoFragment.onCreateView(SupportInfoFragment.java:59)
11-12 14:27:10.180: E/AndroidRuntime(30384):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
11-12 14:27:10.180: E/AndroidRuntime(30384):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
11-12 14:27:10.180: E/AndroidRuntime(30384):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
11-12 14:27:10.180: E/AndroidRuntime(30384):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
11-12 14:27:10.180: E/AndroidRuntime(30384):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
11-12 14:27:10.180: E/AndroidRuntime(30384):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:556)
11-12 14:27:10.180: E/AndroidRuntime(30384):    at com.cookie.jar.activities.AbsBaseaActivity.onStart(AbsBaseaActivity.java:127)
11-12 14:27:10.180: E/AndroidRuntime(30384):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1178)
11-12 14:27:10.180: E/AndroidRuntime(30384):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5198)
11-12 14:27:10.180: E/AndroidRuntime(30384):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2083)
11-12 14:27:10.180: E/AndroidRuntime(30384):    ... 11 more
```

here's my supportinformationactivity:

```
public class SupportInformationActivity extends AbsBaseSingleButtonActivity {

    public static void newInstance(final Activity activity) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(activity, SupportInformationActivity.class);
        activity.startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_support_info);

        final Button infoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_done);
        infoButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        BangoHelper.eventSupport();
        SupportInfoFragment.newInstance(getSupportFragmentManager());
    }

    @Override public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected int getTitleId() {
        return R.string.title_support_info;
    }

    @Override
    public void retryLoginDelayedData(){}

}
```

Here's the logic I am adding under layouts for sw600dp for tablets:

```
 <bool name="isDeviceSupported">true</bool>
    <bool name="isTablet">true</bool>
```

Also my AbsBaseaActivity code :
public abstract class AbsBaseaActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements NoticeDialogListener, LoginListener {

```
    private static final long LOGOUT_PERIOD_IN_MS = 60 * 60 * 1000; // 1 hour
    public final static String TAG_LOGIN_DIALOG = "LoginDialog";
    public final static String TAG_LOGOUT_DIALOG = "LogoutDialog";
    public static final String FAULT_CODE = "FaultCode";

    public static final int RESULT_CLOSE_ALL = 5;

    protected Fragment mActiveFragment;

    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            if (ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION.equals(action)) {
                Log.d("Login","Connectivity changed");
                if (!NetworkUtils.isOnline()) {
                    Log.d("Login","Offline ...");
                    final String text = context.getResources().getString(R.string.offline_message);
                    Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().saveIsOffline(true);
                } else {
                    Log.d("Login","Not Offline");
                    if (shouldRetryLogin()) {
                        Log.d("Login","should retry login is true");
                        Fragment topFragment = FragmentStackManager.getInstance().getTopFragment();
                        /**
                         * Retry Login for all fragments except the Login Fragment
                         * topFragment is null if we are on the Login screen or the dashboard
                         */
                        if (topFragment != null || (mActiveFragment!= null && DashboardFragment.getInstance().getClass().getName().equals(mActiveFragment.getClass().getName()))) {
                            Log.d("Login","retrying Login");
                            retryLogin();
                            if (isHttpCookieRemoved()) {
                                Log.d("Login","restoreCookies");
                                restoreCookies();
                            }
                        }
                        SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().saveIsOffline(false);
                    }
                }
            } else if (BroadcastActions.MULTIPLE_ACTIVE_SESSIONS.equals(action) ) {
                Log.i("ESO1","AbsaActivity: " + AbsBaseaActivity.this.getClass().getName());
                final int faultCode = intent.getIntExtra(AbsBaseaActivity.FAULT_CODE, -1);
                showLoginNoticeDialog(faultCode);
            } else if (BroadcastActions.UPDATE_USER_PREFERENCES.equals(action)) {
                final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                String colorUp = bundle.getString(GenericColumns.COLOR_UP);
                String colorDown = bundle.getString(GenericColumns.COLOR_DOWN);
                String colorFlashing = bundle.getString(GenericColumns.COLOR_FLASHING);
                checkUserPreferencesForUpdates(colorUp, colorDown, colorFlashing);
            }
        }

        private boolean shouldRetryLogin() {
            return SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().getIsOffline();
        }
    };

    private void checkUserPreferencesForUpdates(final String colorUp, final String colorDown, final String colorFlashing) {
        String oldColorUp = SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().getPreferences(MovementSettings.COLOR_UP);
        String oldColorDown = SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().getPreferences(MovementSettings.COLOR_DOWN);
        String oldColorFlashing = SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().getPreferences(MovementSettings.COLOR_FLASHING);
        if (!colorUp.equalsIgnoreCase(oldColorUp) || !colorDown.equalsIgnoreCase(oldColorDown) || !colorFlashing.equalsIgnoreCase(oldColorFlashing)) {
            SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().savePreferences(MovementSettings.COLOR_UP, colorUp);
            SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().savePreferences(MovementSettings.COLOR_DOWN, colorDown);
            SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().savePreferences(MovementSettings.COLOR_FLASHING, colorFlashing);

            refreshScreen();
        }
    }

    public void refreshScreen() {
    }

    public abstract void manageActionBar();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        manageActionBar();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_base_a);
        FragmentUtils.setActivityOrientation(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (hasTimedOut()) {
            SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().setBackgroundTimestamp(0);
            if (SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().shouldAutoSingIn()) {
                if (!LoginActivity.class.getName().equals(this.getClass().getName())) {
                    retryLogin();
                }
            } else {
                goToLoginScreen();
            }
        } else if (isHttpCookieRemoved()) {
            restoreCookies();
        }
    }

    public void restoreCookies() {
        CookieStore cookieStore = SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().getCookieStore();

        if (cookieStore != null) {
            ((NetworkRequestLauncher) NetworkRequestLauncher.getInstance()).setCookieStore(cookieStore);
        }
    }

    public boolean isHttpCookieRemoved() {
        CookieStore cookieStore = ((NetworkRequestLauncher) NetworkRequestLauncher.getInstance()).getCookieStore();
        if (cookieStore != null) {
            List<Cookie> cookies = cookieStore.getCookies();
            if (cookies == null || cookies.size() == 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean hasTimedOut() {
        long backgrountTimestamp = SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().getBackgroundTimestamp();
        if (backgrountTimestamp > 0) {
            long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long backgroundDuration = currentTime - backgrountTimestamp;
            return backgroundDuration > LOGOUT_PERIOD_IN_MS;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
        filter.addAction(BroadcastActions.MULTIPLE_ACTIVE_SESSIONS);
        filter.addAction(BroadcastActions.UPDATE_USER_PREFERENCES);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
        LoginController.getInstance().addLoginListener(this);
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        LoginController.getInstance().clearAuthenticateListeners();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().setBackgroundTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    public void showLoginNoticeDialog(int faultCode) {
        showLoginNoticeDialog(faultCode, false);
    }

    public void showLoginNoticeDialog(int faultCode, boolean isLogin) {
        //We are assuming that a dialog instance is null when not showing and vice versa This
        //is true currently because the only time we are generating a dialog is when we are
        //trying to show it.
        if (LoginCancelSigninDialogFragment.isShowing() || LoginOkDialogFragment.isShowing()) {
            return;
        }


        //DialogFragment.show() is causing illegalstate exception of not allow to do this after onsaveinstancestate
        DialogFragment dialogFragment = LoginDialogFactory.generateLoginDialog(faultCode, isLogin);
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(dialogFragment, TAG_LOGIN_DIALOG);
        ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }

    @Override
    public void goToLoginScreen() {
        setResult(RESULT_CLOSE_ALL);
        LoginActivity.newInstance(this);
        FragmentStackManager.getInstance().clearBackStack(getSupportFragmentManager());
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void retryLogin() {
        final String username = SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().getLoginUsername();
        final String password = SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance().getDecryptedLoginPassword();
        LoginController.getInstance().login(username, password, true);
    }

    public AbsBaseaActivity() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (resultCode) {
        case RESULT_CLOSE_ALL:
            finish();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoginSucceeded() {
        //do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoginFailed(int faultCode) {
        goToLoginScreen();
    }



}
```

I have different activities eith baseactivity supporting most fragments including this one.However, this activity works fine in phone but crashes on the tablet (not sure if its due to the logic added), any idea from the crash log?

Comment: Can you please share what logic you have tried.

Comment: Use your logcat. It's telling you where the NullPointerException occurs. Follow that and find out what's wrong. Most likely, you're using a different layout on tablets, so some of the UI elements aren't where you expect them to be.

Comment: tried, no luck, thats why i posted it on here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the mobile connections thingy is checking the null values, something like this :(which fixed my issue)

```
State mobile = ((conMan.getNetworkInfo(0) == null) ? null : connect to stuff
```

Hope this helps